# asp.net-javascript validation

Tags: asp.net

i have a button..and i want to use javascript to validate certain fields on the button click and if the validation has passed i need to then execute the code in the code behind..any suggestions please guys!

Thanks in advance.

here is my javascript:

```
function validateFields() {

    function checkCampaignStatus() {
        var rdbCampStatus = document.all('<%=rdbCampStatus.ClientID%>');
        var radio = rdbCampStatus.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var isChecked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++)
        {
            if (radio[i].checked)
            {
                isChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isChecked)
        {
            showOk('Save/Close', 'Please fill in all mandatory fields');
            document.getElementById('popupControl').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('divEntryMain').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('divBuilderMain').style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function checkCreatedBy() {
        var createdBy = document.all('<%=txtCreatedBy.ClientID%>').value;
        if (createdBy == "")
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error? Is it in js functions

Answer (score 2):

OnClientClick of the button call the validation function. If the validations are ok , return true else return false. By returning true if the validations are ok it will call the server side method.

Answer (score 0):

Aspx section:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return javascriptFunction()" OnClick"Button_Click"/>
```

JavaScript section:

```
 function javascriptFunction()
 {
      //Get the asp.net server controls using the following code
       var textbox=document.getElementById('<%=txtID.ClientID %>');

       var label=document.getElementById('<%=lblID.ClientID %>');

      if(textbox.value=="")
      {
         label.innerHTML="this is a required field";
         return false;// This will stop at client side and skip server side execution
      }
      else
      {
         return true;//This will execute the server side event
      }

 }
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
function validateFields() {
  return (checkCampaignStatus() && checkCreatedBy());          
}
function checkCampaignStatus() {
        var rdbCampStatus = document.all('<%=rdbCampStatus.ClientID%>');
        var radio = rdbCampStatus.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var isChecked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++)
        {
            if (radio[i].checked)
            {
                isChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isChecked)
        {
            showOk('Save/Close', 'Please fill in all mandatory fields');
            document.getElementById('popupControl').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('divEntryMain').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('divBuilderMain').style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function checkCreatedBy() {
        var createdBy = document.all('<%=txtCreatedBy.ClientID%>').value;
        return (createdBy == "");
    }
```

HTH